# How to resolve Checkstyle error: 'method def modifier ' has incorrect indentation

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

Got a checkstyle error that states a member def modifier has incorrect indentation level 4 and is expected to be level 2.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet (as a text) and a screenshot of the error?

Comment: You have formatting which is not at the expected level. if you are using an IDE format the code using the IDE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having `checkstyle` as a plugin, you must download the its `jar` file as well, just because there you will be able to see what `google` and `sun` check file are doing to your code, and true to be told, it is kind of hard to understand `checkstyle` documentation, and having those files at hand will ease the process to understand what is going on.

Getting back to your question, there is a `module` called `Indentation` which has a property for `basicOffset` that is setting the space it waits to find when scanning your code, I'll show you an example:

```xml
<module name="TreeWalker">
  <module name="Indentation">
    <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
    <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
</module>
```

XML content above shows a simple example, where I want to show you this `module` thing, that's why I added another `property` called `caseIndent` for same `module` called `Indentation` which resides inside `TreeWalker`. As you can see the `basicOffset` property has the number 2 as a `value`, then you could say, wait, the message I got said 4 and not 2. I'll explain it:

```java
class Foo { // no space at the left side
  private void fooMethod() { // a tab or 2 space at the left side
    int a = 0; // 2 space from method's declaration plus 2 for this is 4
  }
}
```

Definively you ought see the `xml` I mentioned before, replicate in your own with basic stuff and play around to have a better understanding. You can get more info form [here](https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html#Indentation).